# openldap and samba error

Tags: server, samba, ldap, openldap

I'm getting an error trying to setup ldap on my ubuntu server with samba.  I'm not a linux guru by any means but trying to learn.  I've looked on the internet for an answer but havent come up with anything useful.

I'm using this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330637

The command I am running is

```
net getlocalsid
```

Just to add something more.  I've installed php ldap admin and I can connect fine.

```
smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for test.com failed with  NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
pdb backend ldapsam:ldap://192.168.10.1 did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
WARNING: Could not open passdb
```

Here is my smb conf file of the area's I've edited.

```
[global]
 # Domain name ..
  workgroup = test.com
  # Server name - as seen by Windows PCs ..
  netbios name = testserver
  # Be a PDC ..
  domain logons = Yes
  domain master = Yes
  # Be a WINS server ..
  wins support = true

   obey pam restrictions = Yes
  dns proxy = No
  os level = 35
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0
  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
  pam password change = Yes

   # Allows users on WinXP PCs to change their password when they press      Ctrl-Alt-Del
  unix password sync = no
  ldap passwd sync = yes

   # Printing from PCs will go via CUPS ..
  load printers = yes
  printing = cups
  printcap name = cups

   # Use LDAP for Samba user accounts and groups ..
 # passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://localhost
  passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://192.168.10.1

   # This must match init.ldif ..
  ldap suffix = dc=test,dc=com
  # The password for cn=admin MUST be stored in /etc/samba/secrets.tdb
  # This is done by running 'sudo smbpasswd -w'.      
  ldap admin dn= cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Nope. I gave up after a while and didn't get any hits on this thread

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I too am stuck at authenticating SMB shares with LDAP.